# Disabling suspend/sleep/hibernate on a headless Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, suspend, hibernate

I'm running Xubuntu 13.10 headless via ssh and tmux. Whenever I leave the machine, making sure to have a tmux session opened, it will invariably crash after about an hour. The sign it has crashed is that `top` says that Xorg is hogging 99% CPU.

As the machine is headless, I cannot do the simple `xset -dpms` that has been suggested many times already. How do I remove every power saving feature that could put the computer to sleep/suspend/hibernate mode when running headless?

Comment: Editing `logind.conf` can help with some off the stuff *(I did an answer a while ago [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/387817/178596) - look for the manual page link)* - but does `top` show a particular process hogging the CPU?

Comment: `top` says Xorg takes 99% of CPU when it crashes. That's how I know it crashed, because I have no other visual cue.

Comment: @wilf I've changed the options in `logind.conf` as you suggested. Let's hope this works!!

Comment: @wilf my computer still crashed :/

Comment: Don't know then :-( - apart from disabling the login screen, I did not have any trouble on my remote box....