# Hack Battery Preference for Gnome 2 MATE on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: power-management, battery, mate

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on my 32-bit computer. However, I missed the Gnome Desktop Environment so I installed MATE 2. I have encountered a problem with  the battery preferences. I don't want to put the PC to a sleep mode when I close the lid. I also don't want to lock my PC or dim the screen when I'm idle. Please tell me how to hack the battery preference for the gnome 2. Thanks.

Comment: Mate isn't officially supported. At least yet.

Comment: But you can [install Gnome](http://askubuntu.com/a/65223/178596).... I did an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/387817/178596) that would be of help, just follow the same steps, and set it to `ignore`. It disables the switch on the Lid being detected and causing suspend. Normally in Ubuntu, this can be done under the 'Power' settings.