# Entirely disable suspension (at kernel level? - has to be independent of used DE and login state!)

Tags: suspend, power-management, login-screen, lock-screen

Once again I need a workaround to deal with my almost broken notebook graphics card: It does not wake up after suspending!

The Ubuntu 14.10 system is waking up, but the display stays off, so I have to press the Power button and blindly navigate to the "Shutdown" option, to avoid a hard power off.

I already disabled suspending for all of my user accounts by following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/488300/367990). However, I now have seen three times when it actually DID do suspending!
That was:

- once after I let my notebook on over night (can't remember last state...)
- once after I closed the lid before I logged into any user account after boot
- once when the notebook was not in use quite a long time (few hours max.) after leaving it on the lock-screen

I think somehow it is still allowed for the system to use suspension and that there is no rule set for the login/lock screen.
Now, can I disable the suspension functionality there too?

---

Update:
I recently installed `lubuntu-desktop` to try LXDE instead of Unity. Now in Lubuntu mode, I can not disable suspending at all. Closing the lid does a suspend which also causes the screen to die until I reboot.
So the solution has to be independent of the used DE!

---

Edit:
Computer information: `lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: dc000000-ddffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000cfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Softmodem
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at de300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: d8000000-d9ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d2000000-00000000d3ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d6000000-d7ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: da000000-dbffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d4000000-00000000d5ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 1860 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at de304000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=07, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: de000000-de0fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02) (prog-if 80 [Master])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374
    I/O ports at 18b0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at 18e0 [size=32]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72M [GeForce Go 7400] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at dc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WM3945ABG MOW2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at da000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at da020000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

05:01.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 18
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=06, subordinate=07, sec-latency=176
    Memory window 0: f4000000-f7ffffff (prefetchable)
    Memory window 1: f8000000-fbffffff
    I/O window 0: 00005000-000050ff
    I/O window 1: 00005400-000054ff
    16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus

05:01.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    Memory at de005000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci

05:01.2 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at de004000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: tifm_7xx1

05:01.3 SD Host controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0753
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    Memory at de005800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
```

Memory info: `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2017       1310        707         14         32        507
-/+ buffers/cache:        770       1247
Swap:          892          1        891
```

Comment: For a laptop lid *(depends on your computer's setup - could you add info on your computer's model and graphics & drivers (`lspci -v`), as well as symptoms of suspending and the output of `free -m`)* doing something with logind might help (I prevously have covered this [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425020/suspend-on-lid-close-even-with-the-option-off/425032#425032) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/387815/13-10-laptop-goes-to-sleep-instead-of-shutting-down-when-lid-is-closed/387817#387817)). Configuring `IdleAction`* might override stuff as well.

Comment: @Wilf thanks for responding. Laptop is a noname model, not even service manuals available. If you want to know anyway, it's a `MaxData Pro 6100 iw`, gfx card is a `nVidia geForce Go 7400` but fried/defect(?), driver is the default xorg, no proprietaries (they don't work at all).

Comment: @Wilf My symptoms are described in the second paragraph of the Q. More detail: system wakes up (I hear sounds, hdd is used,...), but the screen stays black and without background lighting. I can press my power key to open the shutdown/restart/whatever popup (blindly, without seeing anything, of course) and navigate (guessing) with the arrow keys to shutdown, hit enter and wait untill it is off. Then I have to wait another 10-20 minutes until I can reboot, because may gfx card gives me a now white screen (that slowly fades to a strange grey pattern) if I power on while it is still warm.

Comment: @Wilf Oh, and I modified the logind.conf file as you described it, but I don't want to test it right now, because I still have some important things open I can not finish yet. And I still need a solution that covers more than the lid closing, anyway.

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds No, logind.conf was not the right solution. It did not affect LXDE as I remember... I still need something that disables suspending for all triggers (laptop lid closed, low battery, inactive time, shutdown menu, terminal command...) from all users (3 different accounts, nobody logged in), on all DEs (currently Unity, Cinnamon and LXDE) and in best case independent of the used distribution.

Comment: i assume this means you didnt find any solution :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [the solution](https://serverfault.com/a/405387/155817) on Server Fault:

We have to create an executable script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` that will cancel any hibernate or suspend actions.

```
sudoedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/000cancel-hibernate-suspend
```

The content of this file should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
# prevents hibernation and suspend
. "$PM_FUNCTIONS"
case "${1}" in
  suspend|hibernate)
    inhibit
    ;;
  resume|thaw)
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

Now make that file executable:

```
chmod 0755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/000cancel-hibernate-suspend
```

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you very much! :-D

Comment: Related answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189689/103151

Comment: You might look at your bios, and disable suspend there too.

Comment: @Terdon: +100 for you, -100 for me!  ;-)