# black screen after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend, nvidia-prime

My laptop screen goes black after I resume it from suspend while using nvidia as default graphics manager, but when I use Intel graphics as default I dont have this issue. Nothing works, even restarting `lightdm` is useless.

I have pm-suspend.log file [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10593490/)

***NOTE***: I can switch between Intel Intergrated graphics and NVIDIA Dedicated graphics using Nvidia-optimus drivers. NVIDIA graphics card named 820m. I am using nouveau driver v346.47(as shown below).

[image: additional drivers -nvidia drivers - ubuntu]

[image: nvidia control panel ubuntu]

Comment: I have the same problem: system wakes up (can hear sounds, use keyboard/mouse blindly), but screen stays off. nVidia geForce Go 7400 too, but pretty defect... my workaround is to entirely disable suspending. If interested, keep watching my active question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/590710/367990)

Comment: I hahe same problem here. visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/713630/ubuntu-not-starting-after-suspend/713642?noredirect=1#comment1051754_713642

Comment: I have no solution, but a workaround that (almost) always works: go to another terminal (eg. type [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F3]) and then go back to terminal nbr 7:  [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F7]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant but have you looked into booting with nomodeset flag? To test it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu. To make it permanent: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782

Comment: For me  `systemctrl suspend` is a workaround ... see https://askubuntu.com/a/1360185/739504

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with that nouveau driver that is still relevant as of three days ago. I got bricked by a kernel update, had to switch to the nouveau driver and my pet supercomputer basically became unusable with all these exact symptoms, to the letter.

If you still haven't solved this problem, please try this once you get yourself into the text mode with one of those magic key combinations:

first check your kernel version:

`uname -a`

then attempt to install a package `linux-headers` that matches your kernel version. It may say that you're already up to date, which is good. If it tries to install, then good, let it. Something like this:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-<your kernel version from uname>`

After that, install the NVIDIA drivers:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-396`

The latest version that I use is `396`. I'm on `4.13.0-39` kernel. Your version might be different depending on what you're using.

Hope this helps.