# Unable to suspend with nvidia proprietary drivers

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend, nouveau

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and nvidia-340.

With the nvidia drivers enabled I cannot resume from suspend.

I can recover from suspend when I switch to the intel driver or if I use nouveau drivers.

I tried updating the kernel but that didn't solve the issue.

Any way to solve this with the nvidia proprietary drivers?

If not, will I lose a lot of performance by using the nouveau drivers instead of proprietary nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

Suspend/Hibernate/Resume is customizable to add special handling for your graphics card through the `pm-utils` (`utilities and scripts for power management`) package. Read the `man` pages for `pm-action`, `pm-powersave`, `pm-is-supported`, `pm-suspend-hybrid`, `pm-hibernate`, `pm-suspend`, and read the files in `/usr/share/doc/pm-utils/`.

Comment: I follow your advice but didn't find anything that help. I believe the problem should be between the kernel and nvidia drivers. Maybee there is a new driver somewhere that solves the issue ? ppa or something ?

Comment: Idk, but if you find some command line magic to fix your card, it is `pm-utils` where it goes, and `pm-utils` is what stops/restarts it now

Answer (score 0):

By using the latest nvidia-driver-495, I could reset the boot parameters. All back to normal ...

---

*Updated*

Adding the following boot parameters (to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`) did the trick for me:

```
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"
```

[double quotes `"` need to be escaped with backslash `\` in /etc/default/grub]

Props to https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-594328434 (Although I'm not using bumblebee ..)

System consist out of:

- NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] / NVIDIA
  GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
- Running Ubuntu 20.04.3
- Using the nvidia-driver-470

---

As a workaround ***(no longer working ...)*** for me is suspending via the command line (thus not using the topbar "Suspend" nor closing the lid - or the hooks from pm-suspend as I understand):

```
systemctrl suspend
```

---

### Not yet tried (copied) solution form nvidia forum:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-resume-from-suspend-ubuntu-16-04-gt-940mx/51410/172

**Short answer, whats happens** - in resume process Linux (+systemd) forget to turn on monitor. So to solve problem only just need to turn on monitor.

**Short solution (fast test is it helps for you or not)**
`Ctrl+Alt+F1`, you see login prompt, login as normal user (not root) and do (one line command):

```
chvt 7 ; sleep 3; xrandr --display :0.0 --auto
```

**Long solution**
Install 360 driver and install all `nvidia-*.service` & install `/usr/bin/nvidia_sleep.sh`
Install 470 driver (which does not contains this systemd services in `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-*` folders).
Edit `/usr/bin/nvidia_sleep.sh`
and in resume section after chvt command add under your xserver user:

```
sleep 3; xrandr --display :0.0 --auto
```

Also need to add root (may be other) as XServer user, so under your working XSession you need to allow root to execute xrandr:
edit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc and add:

```
xhost +localhost
```

or

```
xhost +root@localhost
```

check it works:

```
sudo su -l xrandr
```

should work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1305452/739504 could worth a try ..

Comment: Here you'll find the current bug, with a solution to get the 470 driver to work: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-resume-from-suspend-ubuntu-16-04-gt-940mx/51410/172