# How to fix NVidia failing to recover from suspend (Ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, suspend, nvidia-optimus

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Asus UX501JW. The laptop has the NVidia Optimus technology (Intel HD4600 and NVidia GM107M (GeForce GTX 960M)). The latest nvidia-384 driver and bumblebee are installed.

After boot-up everything works fine. Until when the laptop gets suspended by closing the lid and then wakes up. Then the syslog is flooded with the below errors and the battery starts draining with 20W as the kernel is trying to reload the failing module. A reboot "cures" it (until the next suspend).

Interestingly - when suspending via the keyboard "Zzz" button this does not happen.

What is the problem and how to fix/workaround it?

```
[  245.095474] NVRM: The system BIOS may have misconfigured your GPU.
[  245.095475] nvidia: probe of 0000:3e:00.0 failed with error -1
[  245.095489] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 2 device(s).
[  245.095489] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[  245.095554] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 243
[  245.180030] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 243
[  245.180254] NVRM: This is a 64-bit BAR mapped above 4GB by the system
               NVRM: BIOS or the Linux kernel, but the PCI bridge
               NVRM: immediately upstream of this GPU does not define
               NVRM: a matching prefetchable memory window.
[  245.180255] NVRM: This may be due to a known Linux kernel bug.  Please
               NVRM: see the README section on 64-bit BARs for additional
               NVRM: information.
[  245.180258] nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
[  245.180265] NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
               NVRM: BAR0 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:3e:00.0)
[  245.180266] NVRM: The system BIOS may have misconfigured your GPU.
[  245.180267] nvidia: probe of 0000:3e:00.0 failed with error -1
[  245.180284] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 2 device(s).
[  245.180284] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
[  245.180372] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 243
```

Comment: On my machine (Dell XPS 15 9550, with nvidia Geforce GTX 960M), with Ubuntu 17.10 (using gnome-shell on top of X11),  I'm seeing a very very very similar error (after suspending and resuming too!)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: I have not found the root cause but at least a **workaround**. After installing the mainline kernel (in my case the version `v4.13-rc6`) the problem does not appear any more.

Instructions to download and install the mainline kernel can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds

Comment: I have another workaround here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1360185/739504 (using `systemctrl suspend`)