# Kubuntu 18.10 + Nvidia won't wake from suspend

Tags: suspend

Upon waking Kubuntu 18.10 from suspend, I simply get a black screen.

I have an Nvidia graphics card; here are the details:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 390.87 bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: fbdev,nouveau FAILED: nvidia unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A direct render: N/A
```

Anyone have some ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 18.10

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/863241/unable-to-suspend-with-nvidia-proprietary-drivers/1360185

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F4` and then `ps aux | grep "xserv"`

And then 
`kill` *(enter_pid_of_xserver_here)*

This usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, most of the time but not every time, on 18.10 with gnome, same graphic card with latest Nvidia driver. 
I can't access to another tty cause the computer doesn't seem to really wake up. 
On a wake up try, the screen backlight doesn't turn on, music don't resume, and I can't ear any HDD sound, only fans seem to turn on.
The only way to get back a working system is to unplug the AC, force shutdown by pressing a few seconds the power button, and wait around 10 secs before pressing it again so that it boots normally (but doesn't resume) and if you don't wait enough time, you get the same void screen of the death.