# Suspend causes reboot, NVIDIA, 19.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend, reboot, 19.04

I have Ubuntu 19.04 with Linux 5.0 (also Linux 4.15-oem installed). I use NVIDIA Proprietary driver. I have i7 6300hq (I think it does not matters) and NVIDIA GTX960m. I added to kernel `acpi_osi=Linux`. On kernel 5.0 when I suspend on Intel profile when I'm waking laptop starts rebooting (but the led is blinking before wake). When I change to NVIDIA profile It suspends and starts normally but wallpaper changes to black and some purple and pink pixels noise (???). When I change to 4.15-oem kernel It suspends normally on Intel profile without any bugs but the NVIDIA PRIME profile don't work. I can change to NVIDIA but after reloging it does not make any change, I am still on Intel.

I've searched to this issue but I found that it was bug in kernel 4.4 and it was on older Ubuntu versions.

PS. I'm using NVIDIA `418.56-0ubuntu1` driver. It is signed in 19.04 as `proprietary, tested`.

Comment: What version Nvidia driver?

Comment: @heynnema, I've added post scriptum to question. It's 418.

Comment: If you open `Software & Updates`, select the `Additional Drivers` tab, what choice do you see?

Comment: @heynnema I can see NVIDIA 418 (proprietary, tested), 410 (proprietary), 390 (proprietary), nouveau (open-source).

Comment: Now I switched to nouveau and as inxi -G says nouveau module is not loaded, I have only i915 driver. Now suspend works as it should but I want to have fully working proprietary driver.

Comment: After selecting nouveau, did you reboot? After reboot, does the nouveau driver seem to work?

Comment: Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, then go to the motherboard/computer makers web site and check for a newer BIOS for your computer.

Comment: @heynnema, I have the latest bios. I use laptop from around 2015. It's ASUS GL552VW (on the internet it's quite problematic model). I have rebooted after fallback to nouveau.

Comment: It sounds like the official Nvidia driver is giving you problems. Nouveau seems to work. I'd communicate your symptoms to Nvidia support.

Comment: @heynnema Ok, I will. Maybe kernel is too new to driver

Comment: Are you aware that there's a Nvidia driver 418.56? If you have 418.0, you might try it.

Comment: The driver was from disco repository so it was exactly `418.56-0ubuntu1 amd64`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

There seems to be a problem with the Nvidia 418.56 driver and Ubuntu 19.04. The user will contact Nvidia support.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/863241/unable-to-suspend-with-nvidia-proprietary-drivers