# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Freezing upon wake up from suspend

Tags: suspend, freeze

This is a recurring problem that I've had with Ubuntu literally since I first started using linux about a year ago. It seems that whenever I have my laptop suspend for about more than 30 minutes, the system freezes upon waking up. I can see the login screen, however I cannot type anything in, nor move my mouse. The only solution is to hold the power button until it turns off. I've researched this problem for a few weeks now, without finding any real solutions. Does anyone have any idea on what I could do to prevent my system from freezing upon wake up?

I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad u430 Touch, with an Intel i5 4210 CPU and Intel® HD Graphics 4000.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but for me, not the system but my graphics card freezes. It is a bit defect, so there was no other option for me than to completely disable suspension. If that might be an option for you too, I would like to provide you the link to the answer that solved my question: [Entirely disable suspending independent of login status and DE](http://askubuntu.com/a/595538/367990)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: "off-topic"? Really?