# How can I wake up my computer from suspend?

Tags: 12.04, suspend, power-management

After the latest update, my machine isn't waking up from suspend, and I have to hard-reboot it. This only happens sometimes, and I can't tell under what exact circumstances it happens. I think it's mostly when it suspends automatically after leaving my machine idle for a while, not when I manually initiate a suspend.

I checked `dmesg`, and I see some messages like `pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI`, but I'm not sure if it's relevant.

How can I debug what is happening, and get my machine to wake properly after suspend?

Edit: This machine is a recent iMac, with an NVIDIA graphics card. It's a desktop.

Comment: To work around the problem, how about just setting the screen to lock after a time, instead of suspending the machine?

Comment: When you get to the point of giving up trying to solve the problem, I can offer you the solution that helped me to entirely disable suspension to prevent freezing: [Entirely disable suspension](http://askubuntu.com/q/590710/367990)

Comment: I don't want to disable suspension--that's just ignoring the problem. I want suspension to work as expected, so that I can wake up my computer from suspend.

Comment: There is a nice set of procedures for debugging the suspend/resume processes located at [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend)

Comment: is this computer a laptop or desktop? when you reset it, do you see warnings about orphaned inodes?

Comment: I'm not sure how it exactly works in case of suspend, but it may depend on available RAM and swap partition size. Are You sure Your swap partition is big enough?

Comment: Perhaps you can write a script in  [/etc/pm/sleep.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pm-action.8.html).

Comment: Using proprietary GPU drivers have sold the problem for some. Can you provide `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`? P.S. Do you use pidgin?

Comment: Sign up for free sealion monitoring, and let the sleep setting go on. Hard shutdown your pc, then paste the sealion logs in the comments.

here is the link to sealion:

sealion.com

Comment: @j0h, I edited my question to indicate what kind of computer it is.

Comment: @VRR, Here's my /var/log/pm-suspend.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10833527/. I don't use pidgin.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**

*Please do be careful*, you are tampering with the bootloader. Make sure your data is backuped.

**First try the setting**

Reboot your pc, boot into grub, highlight Ubuntu , press <kbd>e</kbd> too edit the boot parameters, and   add the parameter specified bellow after line that says `quiet splash $vt_handoff` to try if it works.

```
acpi_osi=Linux
```

**To use it permanently** run in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the parameter on this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

and udapte the bootloader:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: More details please.

Comment: reboot your pc, boot into grub and add above parameter to try if it works. To permanently use it, you'll have to modify your grub bootloader.

Comment: @A.B. i added the explanation on how to do that to s1mmel's answer, check it

Comment: @Serg, looks good

Comment: This was a little difficult to test, since I only experience the non-wakeup issue *sometimes*, like every day or two. I tried adding this line, though, and it didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look around in your CMOS/BIOS settings. In there, there is often a configuration option for waking from suspend. You should change it to something that would probably work, like 'enable suspend' or similar. Hopefully this works, some motherboards override the OS when it comes it waking up.

Be careful, though, don't brick your computer!

Comment: Since my computer is an iMac, I don't have BIOS, I don't think.

Comment: Is there a startup screen, or does it jump straight to the OS? If there is, like an apple logo, that's probably a BIOS. However, I am not familiar with apple devices, so I can't help too much. Try looking up "iMac BIOS". You might need to flash, but I hope not!

Answer (score 0):

Its your graphics driver. You need to update your graphic drivers to latest binaries. You can download them from nvidia's website. Don't forget to remove your installed drivers using `apt-get` before doing anything.