# Laptop shuts down on suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend, shutdown

I recently updated Acer Aspire E5-552 from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. After the update, every time I suspend by system by closing the lid or being idle for a while, my system goes into shutdown instead of suspend.

`uname -a` yields

```
Linux mathijs-Aspire-E5-552 4.17.13-041713-generic #201808061132 SMP Mon Aug 6 15:34:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When reverting to kernel 4.04, my system resumes correctly after suspend. However, kernel 4.04 cannot find my network card, thus reverting back to kernel 4.04 is not an option.

I also changed all behaviour in `gnome-tweaks` from `suspend` to `hibernate`, to no success.

I already tried various ways of altering `grub` like https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556934, but to no avail. Setting the behavious to 'do nothing' like [Laptop suspends on shutdown with lid closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663102/laptop-suspends-on-shutdown-with-lid-closed) does also not provide satisfying results, as my laptop drains much power or can overheat if lid close does nothing. I tried editing `login.conf` but to no avail.

Does someone know what might be wrong?

Comment: maybe this link is useful for you  https://askubuntu.com/a/1059712/790920

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, changing the `gsettings` does not pose any effect.